# Simplfly jQuery and HTML to show/hide divs on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, optimization

I came up with some very basic jQuery using a series of if-statements to show/hide some Divs on a page via an html select list. I would like to optimize this code in a couple ways if possible:

1) How Can I use less code to achieve the same result?

2) This is maybe a bit broad, but how can I optimize this code so that new Divs don't have to be manually typed out? In other words, make it so i don't have to specifically add `$(block-x).hide() $(block-x).show() etc...`

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="selectList">Filter Divs</label>
      <select id="selectList" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" id="lAll" selected="selected">Show All</option>
        <option value="2" id="lOne">One</option>
        <option value="3" id="lTwo">Two</option>
        <option value="4" id="lThree">Three</option>
        <option value="5" id="lFour">Four</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="filterDiv">
    <div id="block-1">
      <h1> Div One</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="block-2">
      <h1> Div Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="block-3">
      <h1> Div Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="block-4">
      <h1>Div Four</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#selectList').change(function() {
  $('#block-1').hide();
  $('#block-2').hide();
  $('#block-3').hide();
  $('#block-4').hide();

  if ($('#lAll').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-1').fadeIn();
    $('#block-2').fadeIn();
    $('#block-3').fadeIn();
    $('#block-4').fadeIn();

  }
  if ($('#lOne').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-1').fadeIn();

  }
  if ($('#lTwo').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-2').fadeIn();

  }
  if ($('#lThree').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-3').fadeIn();

  }
  if ($('#lFour').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-4').fadeIn();

  }

});
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/matts213/29ksshrr/5/

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Change all the blocks to have a common class and then you can use the value of the select to shorten the code:

```
$('#selectList').change(function() {
    var selected = parseInt($('#selectList').val());
    var all = (selected === 1) ? $('.container').children().fadeIn() : false;
    var showItem = (selected > 1) ? $('.container').children(':nth-child(' + (selected - 1) + ')').fadeIn().siblings().hide() : false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mark_c/q5e7x2nc/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's selectors work with CSS so  instead of using each `fadeIn` seperately just place them all in one `css` selector, this reduces your code a bit.

```js
$(function(){


  $('#selectList').change(function() {
  $('#block-1,#block-2,#block-3,#block-4').hide();

  if ($('#lAll').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-1,#block-2,#block-3,#block-4').fadeIn();    
  }
  if ($('#lOne').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-1').fadeIn();

  }
  if ($('#lTwo').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-2').fadeIn();

  }
  if ($('#lThree').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-3').fadeIn();

  }
  if ($('#lFour').is(':selected')) {
    $('#block-4').fadeIn();

  }

});


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="selectList">Filter Divs</label>
      <select id="selectList" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" id="lAll" selected="selected">Show All</option>
        <option value="2" id="lOne">One</option>
        <option value="3" id="lTwo">Two</option>
        <option value="4" id="lThree">Three</option>
        <option value="5" id="lFour">Four</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="filterDiv">
    <div id="block-1">
      <h1> Div One</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="block-2">
      <h1> Div Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="block-3">
      <h1> Div Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="block-4">
      <h1>Div Four</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
$('#selectList').change(function() {

  var divId = +$(this).find(":selected").val();
  var divs = $('.filterDiv').children('div');

  ( divId === 0 ) ? divs.fadeIn() : $('.filterDiv div:nth-child(' + divId + ')').fadeIn().siblings().hide();

});
```

And HTML (improved)

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="selectList">Filter Divs</label>
      <select id="selectList" class="form-control">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Show All</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="filterDiv container">
  <div>
    <h1> Div One</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1> Div Two</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1> Div Three</h1>
  </div>
  <div>    
    <h1>Div Four</h1>
  </div>    
</div>
```

As you can see it's not necessary a bunch of ids. Thus it's not necessary to have a bunch of if else too.

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/29ksshrr/12/).